# Javascript identifier already declared

Tags: javascript

Why does the outer declaration cause an identifier error, while the inner declaration is fine?

```js
function outer() {
  function inner() {
    console.log('Executing inner function');
  }
  var inner = new inner();
}

var outer = new outer();
```

If you change the last line to `var x = new outer();`, it'll run fine.

Comment: I literally copy-and-pasted your code on the console, and it works just fine.

Comment: I get the following: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'outer' has already been declared'. I should note it's being loaded in as a module.

Comment: I created a stack snippet it is working fine. Are you using any linter ?

Comment: I don't believe any linting is happening. I'm running this directly in Chrome, importing that exact script as a module.

Comment: we cannot have a object have the same name as a function.

Comment: you are correct, this works just fine, unless you use this in a module - clearly the language semantics (documented) differ in modules - without the `var` it works as you'd expect

Comment: in a module you can have `var x; var x;` without error, but it seems you can't have `var x; function x(){}` (or the other way around) - though, why you'd want to is a mystery anyway, just makes the code horrible to look at for someone else

Comment: if you REALLY want to use such code ... `var outer=function() { .....}` then `var outer = new outer();` will actually work (with or without the `var` in the second instance) - as to WHY this is the case - and only in the "global" (not really THE global) scope of a module ... I haven't tracked down that documentation :p

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have found the answer yourself. In this case, there is a confusion in the language flow due to the use of the same name for the function (`function outer()`), global variable (`var outer`) and object (`new inner()`). Be more semantic with the name of the functions, variables and objects you intend to use.

Comment: I understand the conflict with outer, I just don't understand the lack of conflict caused by inner, and if that's due to issues relating only to the global namespace, or something else.

Comment: There is no internal conflict due to the scope closed by the function. Unfortunately it is still not a good practice to have the same nomenclature, because as you can attest, problems can happen in variables, objects or functions with the same nomenclature when the scope is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Local and Global declarations of Variables/Objects.

**1. var inner is considered as a local variable and it can have the same name .**

**2. var outer is declared outside of Outer Function. So it is considered as an non local
variable. So it must have an unique name than the existing ones.**

Comment: i meant the Outer function scope

Comment: this only applies in a **module** though ... outside of a module, the code works

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your code in a way that works with your original idea. Basically I read the MDN documentation about possible errors with the new operator. What happens is that the new operator needs a function that defines a scope so that only afterwards can it be stored in a variable and can return whatever you want. In the documentation of this part there are some examples of errors that I believe would clarify your doubts.
[MDN: TypeError: "x" is not a constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor)

```js
function showTheOuterFn() {
  function fnInner() {
    console.log('Executing inner function');
  }
  let getInner = new fnInner();
}

let outer = new showTheOuterFn();
```